# Can you use Cheat Tables with scanmem

Tags: games

Is it possible to use Cheat Tables (`*.ct` files) from the Windows Cheat Engine program with the Linux `scanmem`/`gameconqueror` programs.

If so, how?

BTW, if not packaged for your distro or if your distro packages are ancient (like Debian's, 0.13 from 2012.  Current release is 0.15.8), `scanmem` and `gameconqueror` are available from github at https://github.com/scanmem/scanmem.

Comment: [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1361905) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. .ct files are in XML format and GameConqueror uses JSON. GC has much less functionality. Furthermore, virtual memory addresses on Windows are not compatible with the ones on Linux. So you have to rediscover anyways.

Comment: Actually this is untrue. Cheat tables are in XML like this [bioshock infinite](https://github.com/JMaynard24/CheatEngineTables/blob/master/BioShockInfinite.CT) table. As for the offset being different, I'm unsure if that would be but if so you could possibly script something that could detect the offset dynamically and apply it to your cheats.

Comment: Thanks, edited accordingly. Offsets means pointer following but GameConqueror has no means to follow pointers or to discover offsets. It only uses absolute addresses which only works for static memory in non-PIE executables. Only [ugtrain](https://github.com/ugtrain/ugtrain) is a really working universal game trainer with dynamic memory and ASLR/PIC/PIE support on Linux.